# Using Proxy Server in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android Application for giving PNR status to the input pnr using a json api. But as I am using institute wifi to access network for accessing internet from my android cell phone, so I had set up proxy using the conventional java lines

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "10.3.100.211");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

But when I run the application it abruptly stops. If I comment out the lines the connection is not established but the application runs fine. So could someone help me in how to set up proxy in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
  public static String setProperty (String name, String value)


  Sets the value of a particular system property.
  Returns the old value of the property or null if the property didn't exist.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setProperties%28java.util.Properties%29

Comment: Maybe a permission problem?